# Yarn node manager failed with 0xc0000bb8

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am getting this error in yarn nodemanager:

```
ERROR util.SysInfoWindows: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: PdhAddCounter \Network Interface(*)\Bytes Received/Sec failed with 0xc0000bb8.
Error in GetDiskAndNetwork. Err:1

        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:1008)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:901)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1213)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.SysInfoWindows.getSystemInfoInfoFromShell(SysInfoWindows.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.SysInfoWindows.refreshIfNeeded(SysInfoWindows.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.SysInfoWindows.getPhysicalMemorySize(SysInfoWindows.java:153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.ResourceCalculatorPlugin.getPhysicalMemorySize(ResourceCalculatorPlugin.java:64)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeResourceMonitorImpl$MonitoringThread.run(NodeResourceMonitorImpl.java:143)
```

Using Hadoop 3.3.0 on Windows 10

I found a solution here: https://github.com/apache/hadoop/pull/458
But I do no know what to do exactly. I guess I have to edit the source code for winutils and recreate the .exe-file. But where can I find the source code and how do I generate the .exe?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to change the language of your operation system into English. It helped me.

Comment: Can you elaborate what English? There are many. From UK, US etc.